# How Can i retrieve date from a hashset that contains date and name using linq or contains?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, contains, hashset

I am new to Web API and need help with the code.

I want to return a `boolean` if the date passed is a holiday listed in `GetHolidays` or it is Saturday or Sunday

This is my function where I want to check whether a particular date is holiday or not.

```
public bool IsHoliday(DateTime requesteddate)
{
    HashSet<Holidays> holidays = new HashSet<Holidays>();
    string sat = requesteddate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    string sun = requesteddate.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    holidays = GetHolidays(requesteddate.Year);
    return true;
}
```

This is the hashset of holidays that I have calculated for whole year and that works perfectly

```
public HashSet<Holidays> GetHolidays(int year)
{
    HashSet<Holidays> holidays = new HashSet<Holidays>();

    // NEW YEARS 
    DateTime newYearsDate = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 1, 1).Date);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(newYearsDate, "New Years Day"));

    // MARTIN LUTHER KING, JR. DAY -- third Monday of January
    DateTime martinLutherDay = new DateTime(year, 1, (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 31) where new DateTime(year, 1, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday select day).ElementAt(2));
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(martinLutherDay, "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day"));

    // PRESIDENT'S DAY -- third Monday of February
    DateTime presidentsDay = new DateTime(year, 2, (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 29) where new DateTime(year, 2, day).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday select day).ElementAt(2));
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(presidentsDay, "President's Day"));

    // MEMORIAL DAY  -- last monday in May 
    DateTime memorialDay = new DateTime(year, 5, 31);
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek;

    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        memorialDay = memorialDay.AddDays(-1);
        dayOfWeek = memorialDay.DayOfWeek;
    }

    holidays.Add(new Holidays(memorialDay.Date, "Memorial Day"));

    // INDEPENCENCE DAY 
    DateTime independenceDay = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 7, 4).Date);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(independenceDay, "Independence Day"));

    // LABOR DAY -- 1st Monday in September 
    DateTime laborDay = new DateTime(year, 9, 1);
    dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek;

    while (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        laborDay = laborDay.AddDays(1);
        dayOfWeek = laborDay.DayOfWeek;
    }

    holidays.Add(new Holidays(laborDay.Date, "Labor Day"));

    // VETERANS DAY 
    DateTime veteransDay = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 11, 11).Date);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(veteransDay, "Veterans Day"));

    // THANKSGIVING DAY - 4th Thursday in November 
    var thanksgiving = (from day in Enumerable.Range(1, 30) where new DateTime(year, 11, day).DayOfWeek == `DayOfWeek.Thursday select day).ElementAt(3);
    DateTime thanksgivingDay = new DateTime(year, 11, thanksgiving);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(thanksgivingDay.Date, "Thanksgiving"));

    // DAY AFTER THANKSGIVING DAY 
    DateTime dayAfterThankGiving = thanksgivingDay.AddDays(1);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(dayAfterThankGiving, "Day after Thanksgiving"));

    // CHRISTMAS
    DateTime christmasDay = AdjustForWeekendHoliday(new DateTime(year, 12, 25).Date, true);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(christmasDay, "Christmas"));

    // CHRISTMAS EVE 
    DateTime christmasEve = christmasDay.AddDays(-1);
    holidays.Add(new Holidays(christmasEve, "Christmas"));

    return holidays;
}
```

Here is the IHTTP action in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult IsHoliday(DateTime requesteddate)
{
    try
    {
        var isHoliday = _dateService.IsHoliday(requesteddate);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, isHoliday);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return BadRequest(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: note that `Holidays` should override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

If `Holidays` class implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` by just comparing date portion of the class than just checking for `Contains` will work:

```
var isHoliday = holidays.Contains(new Holidays(requesteddate, "fake"));
```

If `Holidays` class does not implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` pair at all (fix code - [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)) or the class actually compares all fields in these two methods than you need to iterate through all items and compare date manually:

```
var isHoliday = holidays.Contains(h => h.Date == requesteddate);
```

I personally would use `Dictionary<DateTime, Holiday>` instead of `HashSet` as it would be more obvious that that looking up by date with `ContainsKey` will find if date is in the collection.

Side note: `Holidays` is very strange name for single item - normally plural nouns imply collections.

Comment: why mixing _not good_ answer with good answer? :P its really weird to not consider part of the object`s property when computing hash of that object. specially when that property is required for object(i.e not optional)... using Dictionary is definitely the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried buy comparing manually but, whatever date I put the return is false.

Comment: @user1746021 most likely because you've lied to yourself when named  variables - chances are that `requesteddate` is not a date, but current time or something similar. That's why providing [MCVE] is important part of good SO question.

Comment: Hi I have posted the code that worked for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got it this way.... but thanks for help**

```
public bool IsHoliday(DateTime requesteddate, HolidayType type)
{
  var holidays = GetHolidays(requesteddate.Year, type);
  return holidays.Any(h => DateTime.Equals(h.Date, requesteddate));
}
```

Comment: So you're using a hash set but then looping through each item to find one with a matching property?  Why not just override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like has been suggested?